# Java equivalent for PHP's pack function

Tags: java, php, sha1, pack, message-digest

I have a sample application which generates a SHA1 hash in PHP as follows.

```
base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($pass)));
```

I tried to achieve the same in Java, but so far, the output is different. The approach I used is as follows (Base64 and Hex classes come from commons-codec library).

```
    byte[] rawSHA = null;
    byte[] base64HexSHA = null;
    String hex = null;
    MessageDigest md= null;

    // Get Message Digest Instance.
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance(SHA1_ALGORITHM);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        LOG.error("Unable to load SHA-1 Message Digest : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new IllegalStateException("SHA-1 Message Digest Instance Not Found");
    }

    // Build SHA1 Hash
    rawSHA = md.digest(rawText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    // Convert to HEX
    hex = new String(Hex.encodeHex(rawSHA));

    // Encode to Base 64
    base64HexSHA = Base64.encodeBase64(hex.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    // Return String
    return new String(base64HexSHA);
```

My question is, would the approach I have taken yield the same output as PHP's pack() function? My  guess is that PHP pack() function returns the raw bytes where as the Hex.encodeHex returns hex string form (ref : http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_pack.asp).

How can I achieve the same output as PHP's pack() function in Java (or the full output of the above PHP code) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convertion to HEX is not required, just use this:

```
base64HexSHA = Base64.encodeBase64(rawSHA);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My mistake. After going through the pack function description I decided to do a HEX operation on it. Initially it was without hex part, but didn't give me the output. Just now I found that it was because of another issue (the source string  I passed in was not in the format I expected. There was a typo). Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question.
It's good you noticed pack was not needed, bu that doesn't answer the actual question which others would come here for.
Your answer should have been a recommendation after.